# Bootstrap Navbar is not opening when selecting button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Bootstrap navbar </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hidden brand</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>


<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="popper.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

here it is my Complete Bootstrap Navbar Code, it is collapsing when we view it on mobile device, but when we select the button to open the Navbar that time it is not opening.

Comment: Please read the Bootstrap docs: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/#starter-template

Comment: but there is no Tutorial for how to use Bootstrap Navbar

Comment: It explains that you need to include jquery.js, then popper.js, then bootstrap.js which answers the question. It also explains the [Navbar in detail](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/). Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for Sharing Valuable things to me to Learn new things. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK, the problem is the sequence of your js files. Jquery file needs to be first in order for other files to work as they are using jquery.

```
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="popper.min.js"></script>
```

It will work now.

```
<script src="jquery-slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="popper.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sir in Previous Message I Accepted the Answer, I haven't denied the Answer. that's why I type "It Works" how it means that i have denied it ?